# Xamarin, CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: classes.jar : ApkLibraryInstaller$ZipFileInZipEntry.class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have developing Xamarin project for Android and building is failed with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\110\lp\134\jl\bin\classes.jar : com/getkeepsafe/relinker/ApkLibraryInstaller$ZipFileInZipEntry.class MyClient.Android
```

I have no idea why this is causing. This caused after install [Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin](https://github.com/jedusei/Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin) nuget library.

Is there missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update following nuget packages to be latest. (At 28th June 2022)

- [Xamarin.ReLinker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.ReLinker/) (v1.4.4)
- [Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib/) (v1.6.21.1)

[Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin](https://github.com/jedusei/Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin) is depends on Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib (>= 1.5.31) but it should be (>=1.5.31.1)
Also ReLinker needs to be 1.4.4

Reported the issue and has been fixed on [#6](https://github.com/jedusei/Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin/pull/8)